# Failed update of 10.10 results in unbootable system

Tags: 10.10, update-manager, updates

yesterday I performed an automatic security update suggested by the update manager on my virtualized (with VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host) Ubuntu 10.10 installation.

The update somehow failed and left me with an unbootable system. When I try to boot, I am told that various folders, files, and what not are missing. Then the system drops into a busybox and leaves me with an (initramfs) prompt.

This happens with all kernels I get offered by GRUB, although the error messages are quite different from kernel to kernel.

Well, the short of it is this: I don't have the slightest idea on how to get back to a working system and this site is the final straw I'm willing to grab.

A complete disaster like this following an update initiated and executed by the system is unheard of in Windows-land; at least I haven't heard of it, yet, and therefore I am going to abandon Ubuntu and Linux altogeteher, if there is no remedy.

Regards, RSel

Comment: You know, it's nice to know that there lots of different error messages, but it'll be greater to know what exactly that messages are.

Comment: We have no way to help until we know [what the problem actually is](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#describe) — in this case, until we know what error messages are appearing.

Comment: Well, with such an attitude you should better abandon Linux. After all, if you run it in VirtualBox, why didn't you create a snapshot before upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

I have had that problem before and I bit the bullet and re-installed it due to the fact that I needed Ubuntu for a project.

My advice is to download an up to date version of Ubuntu 10.10 ISO image and re-install it.

Just don't give up on Linux and Ubuntu so fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the shift key while Ubuntu is booting, grub should give you the option of recovery mode. You will see a stream of text for a short while and then a screen with several options in a list. Select repair broken packages and hit enter. Follow any prompts to download and install and then reboot. It is worth a try. Failing that you may want to reinstall.